# React Native 0.60.3 babel-plugin-transform-remove-console not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I am trying to remove console.log outputs from my react-native application's output, but when I run

> ENVFILE=.env.production react-native run-android --variant=release

and

> adb logcat

I still see my app's data being logged to the console.

I used the following documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements.

Here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing ?
Im on react-native 0.60.3
and using "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution to this? I am also getting this, however I am using `babel.config.js`

Comment: Sorry mate, had to move on. I've been using the following as a workaround. Its a bad workaround but I still have my job. 
function noop () {}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log = noop;
  console.warn = noop;
  console.error = noop;
}

Comment: Thanks anyway! I ended up doing this in my babel.config.js, since it can export a function:

module.exports = function(api) { api.cache(true); if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.BABEL_ENV === 'production') { return { "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"], "plugins": ["react-native-paper/babel", "transform-remove-console"] } } else { return { "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"], } } } 

Sorry for the single line, in the comment haha. Seems to work properly

Comment: Added it as an answer

Comment: @ThembelaniM You might have moved on, but still it would be a good idea to accept an answer that works! :) Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have `"@babel/core": "^7.5.5"` and `"react-native": "^0.60.5"`
The approach descibed in [React Native Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements) was not working for me.
After many try and error and exploring issues on GitHub I got it working :

In **babel.config.js** add this -

```
module.exports = api => {
  const babelEnv = api.env();
  const plugins = [];
  //change to 'production' to check if this is working in 'development' mode
  if (babelEnv !== 'development') {
    plugins.push(['transform-remove-console', {exclude: ['error', 'warn']}]);
  }
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins,
  };
};
```

> To see changes run using `npm start -- --reset-cache`

More Info at

- https://github.com/babel/minify/issues/934
- https://github.com/babel/minify/issues/950#issuecomment-539590159

Comment: The npm start -- --reset-cache comment really helped too. Changes weren't viewable until I ran that. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt, I have been stuck with this issue. Ran the npm start -- --reset-cache command and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using `babel.config.js` instead of `.babelrc`, it seems that `process.env.BABEL_ENV` is used to determine whether to include configs listed under `env.production`. However, `process.env.BABEL_ENV` is set to `undefined` during build.

To get around this, I'm returning a different object depending on if `process.env.BABEL_ENV` OR `process.env.NODE_ENV` indicate production build.

YMMV.

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true); // necessary
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.BABEL_ENV === 'production') {
    return {
      "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
      "plugins": ["react-native-paper/babel", "transform-remove-console"]
    }
  } else {
    return {
      "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

install [babel-plugin-transform-remove-console](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console)

```
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-remove-console -D
```

then add follow code in **babel.config.js** like this

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  const babelEnv = api.env();
  api.cache(true);
  const plugins = [
    [];
  if (babelEnv === 'production') {
    plugins.push(['transform-remove-console', {exclude: ['error', 'warn']}]);
  }
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins,
  };
};
```

then run this command

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```

#### NOTE:

this will remove console.log in the **production** build. if you wanna a test in **development** you can pass **development** instead of **production**

Comment: from the docs
Note: This function internally makes use of api.cache mentioned above to ensure that Babel is aware that this build depends on a specific envName. You should not use it alongside with api.cache.forever() or api.cache.never().